# Why does Visual Studio 2005 take so long to update my VSMDI file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, microsoft-test-manager

I am using a solution with many projects in Visual Studio 2005. Unfortunately we are using the testing tools. My problem is that a lot of the time when I open up Test Manager by double clicking on my VSMDI file to do some testing, I get the hourglass for at least 10 minutes while Microsoft's horrible code does god-knows-what, I guess trying to find new tests? Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is now an old question, but I've got used to using MSTEST now. Here's my recommendations for effective use in a large solution:

- Use the shortcuts CTRL-R, T (or CTRL-T for debug) to run the tests in the current context (i.e. namespace, class, method). This fits reasonably well with a TDD approach.
- Don't use Test View, Test Lists or Test Runs windows if you can avoid it.
- Generally I find I only get problems with the VSMDI file when switching between different build configuration. VS thinks for a while then prompts me to check out the VSMDI file (and I just cancel the check-out dialog).